# How to test audio channels of headphone

Tags: audio, headphones, headset

In right side of my headset (Asus Cerberus Headset) bass sounds hit my ear heavier than left side. But there is no audible difference in other sounds/channels.

I had sent this headset to service and they told "both sides have same volume".

**I just want to check my headset channels to recognize exact problem** and send it  again to service. Is there any program to check audio channels?

I don't know what I can write more. It is impossible to adjust levels because of channel difference. And this is not related to OS. Same in Windows, Linux and Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

And when you reverse the headset in "wrong" position; is the bass heavier on the other ear then? If not, it is ear damage (or blockage), not headphones. Otherwise it is headphones, replace them.

Comment: Yes, when i use it in wrong position i hear heavier from my left ear.

It is not easily recognizable when I play stereo sounds like musics or game tracks. But it is obvious in sounds like news' speaker voices.

Comment: Then next test is use a different sound source, your TV etc rather than computer, & test both right & wrong ways again. If same, it's the headset, if different, it's the computer. You could also test with VLC player: Audio > Audiochannels > Reverse Stereo.

Comment: I tried on 2 different computers and Samsung S4. There is a problem in headset, I am sure. I just want to test it with different channels in headset.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "check my headset channels?"  There is only left and right channels.  Perhaps you mean different frequencies?  You mentioned the bass was louder in one ear then the other in your original post.  Then in your reply, you said voices aren't balanced.  Either way, if you tried the "wrong" position test and the balance is reversed, then the headphones is bad.  Just replace it.

Comment: There are 5+1 speakers and I think for headsets there must be different channels for direction of sound. Or maybe different channels for bass sounds. These what I mean. This is gaming headset and otherwise headset can not say where enemies are for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, the headset you have only supports 2.0 channels.  Any "surround" sound you may hear is simply the illusion of sound processing from your computer.  All 5.1 sound sources will be "down-mixed" into 2 channels.  The center and bass channel will come out of both speakers, the front and rear left will come out of the left, and same for the right.  If you look at the specs page form the Asus website, your headset uses one  60mm driver for each ear.  Also, it uses the standard 3.5mm audio jack which only supports 2.0 channels.